# Histogram of data with error in matlab

Tags: matlab

Good day,

I am trying to create a normalized histogram in matlab, in which the error in the number of elements in each bin is incorporated.

So I've got the code working if I do NOT do anything with the error in the number of elements in each bin. I have a dataset of 250000 elements, which are actually 5000 repetitions of 50 measurements, so I reshape it first. The data is all integers by the way, most often 0, 1 or 2 but sometimes a little higher.

```
ROdata = somedataset of 250000 values;
A = reshape(ROdata,50,5000);
% sums the values in every column
sums = sum(A);
% makes sure the bin ranges are from 0 to max in steps of 1
MAX = max(sums);
binranges = 0:1:MAX;
%determines the number of counts in each bin
bincounts1 = histc(sums,binranges);
%makes sure the distribution is normalized
bincounts2 = bincounts1 ./ sum(bincounts1);

%determine mean, sd of mean and chance of obtaining 0 counts
meanms1 = mean(sums);
sdms1 = std(sums);
figure
bar(binranges,bincounts2,'histc');
xlabel('Counts')
ylabel('Probability')
```

So this is fine, and it creates the histogram just like I want it to be. But the dataset that I have is not perfect, it is a measurement that is influenced by shot noise, so the counts have an error of squareroot(count number).

So the error, which I suppose enters starting at

```
sums
```

is simply

```
sumserror = sqrt(sums);
```

However, I don't know how to incorporate this into the rest of the script, so that these errors are still taken into account. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Your question is not clear - are you asking how to calculate errors or how to visualize errors?

Comment: Hm, I apologize. What I am asking is how I incorporate the fact that 'sums' is not actually 'sums', but 'sums +- sumserror' in the final histogram. 

But maybe the histogram is not the ideal place for this. All in all the histogram is only a visual aid for my purposes, what I am really interested in is the probability of having 0 counts (in which I need to know the error in the probability), the average number of counts and the error in this average.

Comment: so for that the [Wikipedia on Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) is quite complete.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks, much appreciated. In combination with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty it is indeed rather straightforward.